# Stuck on git rebase while merging diverged branches

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase

I have a local branch with 5 commits not in remote branch while remote branch has 6 commits not in my local branch.

I squashed my local commits into a single commit, now i have 1 commit in local branch. I did
"**git pull --rebase**" and it said there are conflicts. I fixed the conflict files and did "**git add**" on all those file. Now when i do "git status" it says im not in any branch and i have a bunch of file that need to be commited. So i did a "**git commit**" on all the files and checked out to my local branch and did "**git rebase --continue**". Now it says there are no files to commit and im back to original status with 1 commit in local and 6 commits in remote and im still in the middle on the rebase !!.

Can some one please shine light on whats happening to my repo ??

Comment: you probably should not have commited, but just ran `git rebase --continue`. Copy your working dir (or at least the conflict resolved files, so you don’t loose your work) and run `git rebase --abort`. Now do it again, but this time without the commit.

Comment: before moving to my local branch ? i.e when im not in any branch ?

Comment: great it fixed it, i thought since i was not in any branch i had to move to my local branch and continue the rebase. may be i should read the git docs properly. but thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Moved my commit to an answer so this question has an answer – I hope this is the correct SO way. Just a note: You should not care about what branch you “are on” during rebase. You are not on any branch or anything – you are rebasing :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably should not have commited, but just ran `git rebase --continue`.

Copy your working dir (or at least the conflict resolved files, so you don’t loose your work) and run git `rebase --abort`. Now do it again, but this time without the commit.